Chrome extention that download a page source code
This is my first chrome extension and here's what I've managed to do.
The purpose of the extension is to download the source code of certain web pages and then refresh the page after a few seconds, and so on. This allows me to obtain the source code of these pages in text format every 10s and analyze them with software to detect any changes.
However, I have the impression that the browser is getting slower with time.
I always have 4 to 6 tab open in the same time because there is that amount of page to permacheck.
As this is the first time I've done javascript and browser extensions, I'm not sure I've done things correctly.
There are a few bits of code I don't understand (those marked idk).
Here's my code:

manifest.json

{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "YggRSS",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Obtention du flux RSS depuis Yggtorrent",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","downloads","management"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "YggRSS"
    }
}


background.json

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {    
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        // Check if this is my target
        var expression = /mywebsite.*status/;
        if (expression.test(tab.url)) {
            
            // Get source code
            fetch(tab.url)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    // Check if sourcecode contains statusdetails
                    if (data.includes("atom-78")) {
                        // File name will be like sc_78_.txt for a page with the id 78
                        const match = tab.url.match(/id=(\d+)/);
                        if (match && match[1]) {
                            const id = match[1];
                            const filename = 'sc_' + id + '_' + '.txt';

                            // Idk but it works
                            const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
                            const urlData = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                            // Download the file
                            chrome.downloads.download({
                                url: urlData,
                                filename: filename,
                                conflictAction: 'uniquify',
                                saveAs: false
                            }, (downloadId) => {

                                // // After 8s, remload (don't works with more that 10s)
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: tab.url });
                                }, 8000);
                            });

                            // Idk but looks required
                            URL.revokeObjectURL(urlData);
                        } else {
                            alert('No id found.');
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Page load fail, reload
                        setTimeout(() => {
                                    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: tab.url });
                                }, 10000);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert('Unknown error', error);
                });
        }
    }
});


Change your timeouts so you only have one active at a time
let tId;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener
...
  clearTimeout(tId)
  tId = setTimeout(() => {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: tab.url });
  }, 8000);
...
else {
  clearTimeout(tId)
  tId = setTimeout(() => {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: tab.url });
  }, 10000);

If you have several tabs you can use an object for the tIds
const timeoutMap = {};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && /mywebsite.*status/.test(tab.url)) {
    // Clear any previous timeout to avoid multiple reloads
    if (timeoutMap[tabId]) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutMap[tabId]);
      delete timeoutMap[tabId];
    }

    fetch(tab.url)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.includes("atom-78")) {
          const match = tab.url.match(/id=(\d+)/);
          if (match && match[1]) {
            const id = match[1];
            const filename = `sc_${id}_.txt`;
            const blob = new Blob([data], {
              type: 'text/plain'
            });
            const urlData = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            chrome.downloads.download({
              url: urlData,
              filename: filename,
              conflictAction: 'uniquify',
              saveAs: false
            }, () => {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(urlData);
              // Schedule a reload after 8 seconds
              timeoutMap[tabId] = setTimeout(() => {
                chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
                  url: tab.url
                });
              }, 8000);
            });
          } else {
            alert('No ID found.');
          }
        } else {
          // Schedule a reload after 10 seconds if the page fails to load correctly
          timeoutMap[tabId] = setTimeout(() => {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
              url: tab.url
            });
          }, 10000);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => alert('Unknown error', error));
  }
});


I have 4 to 6 page to check in the same time, so there is always 4 to 6 tab open that run the script. Sorry I forgot to specify that.

What do you mean only one at the time? Isn't the sricpt reset each reload?

Every time the onUpdated event is triggered you will get a new setTimeout.

So after 20 reload I will have 20 running timeout? I modify the script according to your instructions.

You will have as many setTimeouts as there are setTimeouts that haven't yet run out, yes.

If you need one per tab, make an object to store the tIds in.

Ty for your tips but I'm sorry, this is my very first js code, can you show me how to do that? You can create an answer of the question and I will validate it.
